# Visual representation of an element I am clicking in VS Code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I think remember reading this somewhere but cannot remember if it is true or not. Is there a VS Code extension that will let you visually see on the web page (or in VS Code) where exactly the `mouse.click` event is happening and what element is therefore receiving the click?

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

According to the Selenium documentation it **always** attempts to click within the center of the given element, so seeing it visually seems a bit redundent:

> The element click command is executed on the center of the element. If
> the center of the element is obscured for some reason, Selenium will
> return an element click intercepted error.

[Source](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/interactions/#:%7E:text=The%20element%20click%20command%20is,an%20element%20click%20intercepted%20error.)

If however you want to see what it might be clicking at a specific point in time, you could take a couple of screenshots as needed with something like:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises

function takeScreenshot(driver, file){
  return driver.takeScreenshot()
    .then(image => fsp.writeFile(file, image, 'base64'))
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185175/3324415)